# Constructors String in Int

Tags: java, swing

I would like to display each items from my variable named CodeA (type String) in a JcomboBoxe. I have an error message :

> no suitable constructor found for `Album(int, String)` constructor `Album.Album()` is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor `Album.Album(String, String, Chanteur, Date)` is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

```
ArrayList<Album> listeCats = daoLoc.selectAlbums();
listeCats.add(0, new Album(0,"*")); 

for (Album cat : listeCats) 
{
    jComboBoxChanteur.addItem(cat); 
}
```

So my problem is in my constructor Album?

```
public class Album 
{
    private String codeA;
    private String titreA;
    private Chanteur chantAlb;
    private Date dateApp; 

    public Album() {}

    public Album(String codeA, String titreA, Chanteur chantAlb, Date dateApp) 
    {
        this.codeA    = codeA;
        this.titreA   = titreA;
        this.chantAlb = chantAlb;
        this.dateApp  = dateApp;
    }
}
```

I don't understand the conversion between `String` and `Int`

Edit: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Qto.png)

Comment: "*I don't understand the conversion between String and Int*" - There is none. Only "built-in" conversion is when you use string concatenation. Your code does not compiile because you try to  call a constructor `Album(int, String)`, but this constructor does not exist.

Comment: Normally, I will should  call only a String in my constructor ? :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two constructors: The default one and one that accepts a `String`, `String`, `Chanteur` and `Date`.

Then you try to create a new `Album` object like this:

```
new Album(0,"*")
```

(You have trying to create an `Album` object with  an `int` and `String` as the constructor arguments.)

You need to either add arguments to match one of your constructors or create a new one that accepts only an `int` and `String`.

EDIT:

If you simply want to create a new constructor to accept an `int` and `String` you would have to create a new `int` variable and then make new constructor:

```
int newVariableName;
public Album(int codeA, String titreA) {
    this.newVariableName = codeA;
    this.titreA = titreA;
}
```

OR if `0` is supposed to be a String add quotation marks around it:

```
new Album("0","*")
```

Comment: I should create an argment here (0,new Album(0,"*")); and in the constructor but what ?

Comment: almost, the 0 after Album contains a problem listeCats.add(0, new Album(0,"*")); the message is "incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String" :-s

Comment: @juliiiie See my new edit. Is `0` supposed to be a String? I'm not really sure why you're passing these arguments to the constructor

Comment: @ GBlodgett:  I don't have of error message thank you a lot, however in my jComboBoxe the are several weird writting "transfertObjectAlbum" see screenshot (first message)

Comment: I think the 0 is not important ? I just must to recuperate string

Comment: @juliiiie I would recommend asking a new question with the relevant code. (Each question on SO should only have one topic, and this question doesn't have the relevant code)

Comment: @ GBlodgett opppsss sorry thank you a lot for your help... :-) Good night and mercy